# How to add sound recording to a java based website - preferably a open source solution

Tags: java, open-source

I need to add functionality to a website to allow users to record a short sound snippet with their microphone.

I understand that this is possible with flash - but is there a free solution?

Ideally I was hoping this could be achieved without using applets.

Does JavaFX or flex provide this functionality?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying you don't mind JavaFX but don't want applets? Currently this functionality is neither part of JavaFX nor the PlugIn.

Comment: I'm just looking for a simple usable solution - ideally I don't want a heavyweight java applet. A simple quick loading applet would be great. I'm also interested in the server side support required for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out the Java Sound samples [here](http://www.jsresources.org/examples/). I think you always need some 3rd party browser extension (flash, applet, silverlight, etc).